# What happens with Azure Resource Groups when an azure region is lost?

Tags: azure, disaster-recovery, azure-resource-group

I know that Azure Resource group must be created with a location, because that is where the metadata for that RG will reside.

Our application currently has a resource group in a location (eg : East US) that contain resources located in multiple regions. (eg : East US and Central US).

What happens to my Central US resources if East US goes down?

To be more specific :

- Does the availability of the region hosting the RG itself affect the availability of the resources in another Region? (My guess in the example above is that the resources in Central US should still be running ok).
- In the example above, is it still possible to manage the Central US resources if the location hosting the RG (East US) is down? This one is much less clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. no, the availability of the region Resource Group hosted in doesn't affect availability of the resources in it.
2. you can only read those resources, as Resource Group region is responsible for writes
3. you won't be able to use template deployments as well
4. in regions with zones all zones have to go down for writes to be not available.

reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview#resource-groups

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Any chance you have links to official Microsoft documentation that backs up your answer?

Comment: no, but this information is coming directly from people who own this service in Azure

Comment: I'm trying to get an official word from MS on this. I'll accept your answer for now (it makes sense!) and come back here if I ever get confirmation (or other info) from MS directly. Thanks!

Comment: Microsoft confirmed this and updated their documentation following my question. You can't make changes to resources in a RG If the region hosting the RG is down. Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview#resource-groups